# pandas, как узнать сколько потребовалось строчек что бы сложить значения в столбце в сумме до 20?

Tags: python, pandas

> Условие задачи: Сколько дней у ресторана было менее 20 успешных
> заказов?

```
    date      vendor_id successful_orders
39182   2019-06-06  58395   3.0
16289   2019-06-07  58395   1.0
72353   2019-06-11  58395   2.0
57402   2019-06-13  58395   2.0
60595   2019-06-15  58395   2.0
4811    2019-06-17  58395   2.0
41577   2019-06-18  58395   2.0
89448   2019-06-19  58395   2.0
91519   2019-06-20  58395   1.0
25444   2019-06-21  58395   1.0
7956    2019-06-23  58395   1.0
47692   2019-06-24  58395   1.0
30362   2019-06-26  58395   3.0
11791   2019-06-28  58395   1.0
61300   2019-06-29  58395   1.0
47651   2019-06-30  58395   1.0
46090   2019-07-01  58395   4.0
50288   2019-07-02  58395   2.0
55434   2019-07-03  58395   2.0
74493   2019-07-05  58395   4.0
```

Как мне складывать столбец только до тех пор пока не будет нужной суммы, а потом вывести сколько на это потребовалось строчек?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html

Comment: Спасибо за линк. получил такое dbSorted["successful_orders"].cumsum(axis=0).head(12) на выходе он выдает массив с подсчетами. а как сделать что бы он считал сколько строк потребовалось что бы дойти до нужного числа?

Comment: 1. `cumsum` 2. `<20` 3. `count`

Answer (score 3):

Считаем `cumsum`, делаем фильтр по всем получившимся значениям, которые меньше  заданного лимита, суммируем значения `True`.

```
(df.successful_orders.cumsum()) < 20).sum()
```

**UPD**
Спасибо Алексей Р за подсказку в комментариях.
Применение метода `.lt()` вместо сравнения дает экономию во времени исполнения кода около 30%. Вот окончательное решение:

```
df.successful_orders.cumsum().lt(20).sum()
```

Comment: Решение правильное, но можно сделать немного аккуратнее `....cumsum().lt(20).sum()`

Comment: @АлексейР Благодарю! Исправил ответ, указал Вас в ответе.

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь у меня больше появляется понимания о структуре записи)

Answer (score 0):

Судя по условию задачи ("Сколько дней у ресторана было менее 20 успешных заказов?"), вам не нужно складывать значения в столбце, а нужно узнать количество значений в столбце, которые меньше 20.

```
lst = []
for i in df['successful_orders']:
    if i < 20:
        lst.append(i)
len(lst)
```

Comment: Поищите решение получше, это не для pandas

Comment: и не является решением, т.к. для приведённого примера вернёт длину всего списка. а должно вернуть 11 (если я правильно в уме посчитал).

Comment: Одна строка - один день, в последнем столбце - количество заказов. Если количество заказов менее 20, мы считаем не это количество, а этот день. Из условия следует, что нужно вернуть количество строк, а брать строку нужно, если в последнем столбце число меньше 20...
    
    bad_days_cnt = df['successful_orders'].loc[df['successful_orders'] < 20].count()